# Restangular adding format=json to the end of url. How to remove?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

```
$scope.getSearchResults = function(table, query, limit, results, callback){

    var baseApi = Restangular.all('Search?type=1&searchText=filterQuery&format=json&$top=5');

    baseApi.getList().then(function(results){
        callback(results);
    });

}
```

after function call I get this url with **format=json** in the end. How to remove it?

api/Search?type=1&searchText=filterQuery&format=json&$top=5?**format=json**

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but this is probably set up as a parameter in [setDefaultRequestParams](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#setdefaultrequestparams).